# Is it possible to find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with only two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

One of the exercises I did recently is the following:

Find a basis of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ consisiting of all vectors of the form:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  x_1\\
  -5x_1 + x_2\\
  5x_1 - 8x_2\\
  -9x_1 + 7x_2
\end{array}
\right] $$

The solution to this problem is $\{(1,-5,5,-9), (0,1,-8,7)\}$.

How is it possible to have a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with only 2 vectors? Don't I need 4 of them? With 2 vectors, the most I can get is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, because they only span a plane, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: ... a basis of **the subspace of** $\mathbb R^4$... not a basis of $\mathbb R^4$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a basis of *all* of $\Bbb{R}^4$.  That's a basis of the 2-dimensional *subspace* that the given vector traces out as $x_1$ and $x_2$ are varied.  It's a plane, a copy of $\Bbb{R}^2$, sitting in an ambient $\Bbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Now that makes a lot of sense. I never thought of it that way, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just  look carefully the statement  " find a basis  of the subspace of $ R^4$ "
You are to find the basis for the subspace $W$ which has dimension 2 ( look carefully)

Answer (score 0):

No.  $\Bbb R^4$ is four dimensional, so requires a basis consisting of four vectors.  As was stated, what you have is a basis for a ***subspace*** of $\Bbb R^4$.  A two dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x_1= 1$ and $x_2= 0$ so that $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\-5 \\ 5 \\ -9 \end{bmatrix}$.  Take $x_1= 0$ and $x_2= 1$ so that $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -8 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}$.

Those form a basis for this two dimensional space.